# Nextion IDE Frame layer priority

Tags: ide, embedded, microcontroller, touchscreen, nextion

I recently purchased the Nextion 2.4" touchscreen. I have run some test code that allows me to switch images on the current page. The image will overlap the buttons when the image is called. Is there a way to have the button be on the lop layer at all times, that is to say, is there a way to make the buttons have higher priority?

http://wiki.iteadstudio.com/Nextion_HMI_Solution